# C Plugins for Jenkins & Unit Test Framework support?

Tags: c++, c, jenkins

I want to use Jenkins in Embedded development project with either C or C++ language.As i am a Beginner to start with Jenkins , i want to know what are the plugins for Jenkins for C and C++, and which is the C Unit Test Framework it supports?
Pls Help ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [the xUnit plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/xUnit+Plugin) for your tests.
You can read this post about testing on C [link](http://www.van-porten.de/2009/05/cunit-tests-in-hudson/).